# Getting sound from rear panel and front panel in same time

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

I am getting sound from rear panel and front panels in same time. I am using Realtek HD audio driver 6.0 . I was looking front panel jack detection in Realtek driver interface but i couldn't find it too .

What can cause this problem and how can i fix it ?

Comment: First thing to check: Have you got latest drivers for your Soundcard/Motherboard?

Comment: I think it is latest but i suspect that it is about drivers configs

Comment: Windows 7? Windows XP? Motherboard model?

Comment: Saphire Tech PI-AM3RS785G mainboard and Windows 7

Comment: Check out this thread and try playing with some of the settings they are talking about in there: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/230110-28-realtek-front-panel-jack-working

Comment: Jack detection is implemented in silicon and exposed via the driver interface. It cannot be toggled by the user without driver hooks.